# Karate Framework handling radio button

Tags: user-interface, selenium-webdriver, automation, radio-button, karate

I am trying to assert a radio button clicked by default when page is loaded. Is there any idea how can I do it?

I automate a web application with Karate framework and not sure how to handle a radio buttons.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot depends on the HTML.

But this *may* work:

```
* def val = value('.my-locator')
* match val == 'on'
```

Note that `value()`, `attribute()` and even `html()` can be used to get ALL data about the HTML element. Refer the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#value